# How to set TMUX window using set title option?

Tags: neovim, terminal, tmux

In neovim source code title option is set as follows at https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/73c7a0d58e6358d35fe2d5a11b3e807a625a0001/src/nvim/tui/tui.c#L1460 :

```
void tui_set_title(TUIData *tui, String title)
{
  if (!(unibi_get_str(tui->ut, unibi_to_status_line)
        && unibi_get_str(tui->ut, unibi_from_status_line))) {
    return;
  }
  if (title.size > 0) {
    if (!tui->title_enabled) {
      // Save title/icon to the "stack". #4063
      unibi_out_ext(tui, tui->unibi_ext.save_title);
      tui->title_enabled = true;
    }
    unibi_out(tui, unibi_to_status_line);
    out(tui, title.data, title.size);
    unibi_out(tui, unibi_from_status_line);
```

The `unibi_to_status_line` seems to be constant and hardcoded in NVIM and set in TMUX at https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/73c7a0d58e6358d35fe2d5a11b3e807a625a0001/src/nvim/tui/tui.c#L1918C28-L1918C48 :

```
  } else if (tmux) {
    unibi_set_if_empty(ut, unibi_to_status_line, "\x1b_");
    unibi_set_if_empty(ut, unibi_from_status_line, "\x1b\\");
    unibi_set_if_empty(ut, unibi_enter_italics_mode, "\x1b[3m");
    unibi_set_if_empty(ut, unibi_exit_italics_mode, "\x1b[23m");
```

How can I change `unibi_to_status_line` to `\x1bk` so that it sets window name in tmux, not pane name? Doing `let &t_ts="\ek"` doesn't seem to set it. I am not able to follow `unibi_to_status_line` symbol further, where it's definition?